# UsernameNotFoundException returned although user exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've a Spring Boot project with the following DAO:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    
    // method to sort by last name
    public List<User> findAllByOrderByLastNameAsc();
    public Optional<User> findByEmail(String emailAddress);

}
```

It also has a service with the following findByEmail():

```
@Override
public User findByEmail(String theEmail) {
        
    Optional<User> result = userRepository.findByEmail(theEmail);
    User theUser = null;
    if(result.isPresent()) {
        theUser = result.get();
    }
    else {
        // we didn't find the user
        throw new RuntimeException("Did not find userId: " + theUser);
    }
    return theUser;
}
```

When I run my application I get a `UsernameNotFoundException` and can see that the query seems to be executed correctly. It should return 1 record. The below log says the result set is 0 but also shows the correct address of the user I was trying to access:

```
2020-12-05 16:30:55.687 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.address_line1 as address_2_3_, user0_.address_line2 as address_3_3_, user0_.birth_date as birth_da4_3_, user0_.country as country5_3_, user0_.county as county6_3_, user0_.email as email7_3_, user0_.first_name as first_na8_3_, user0_.gender as gender9_3_, user0_.last_name as last_na10_3_, user0_.membership_status as members11_3_, user0_.mobile as mobile12_3_, user0_.password as passwor13_3_, user0_.phone as phone14_3_, user0_.postcode as postcod15_3_, user0_.town as town16_3_ from users user0_ where user0_.email=?
2020-12-05 16:30:55.691 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : **Result set row: 0**
: Result row: EntityKey[com.me.clubmanager.entity.User#1]
2020-12-05 16:30:55.695 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.me.clubmanager.entity.User#1]
2020-12-05 16:30:55.696 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `addressLine1` : value = **3 Main Street**
2020-12-05 16:30:55.696 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`addressLine1`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-12-05 16:30:55.696 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `addressLine2` : value = null
2020-12-05 16:30:55.696 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`addressLine2`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-12-05 16:30:55.696 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `authorities` : value = NOT NULL COLLECTION
2020-12-05 16:30:55.696 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`authorities`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-12-05 16:30:55.697 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : rolling back
2020-12-05 16:30:55.871 DEBUG 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/showMyLoginPage?error", parameters={masked}
```

It also states `Processing attribute` authorities `: value = NOT NULL COLLECTION` which I think may be where my problem lies.

Below is my user and aut

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    
    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",
            cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    // define fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    
    @Column(name="address_line1")
    private String addressLine1;
    
    @Column(name="address_line2")
    private String addressLine2;
    
    @Column(name="town")
    private String town;
    
    @Column(name="county")
    private String county;
    
    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;
    
    @Column(name="postcode")
    private String postcode;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name="mobile")
    private String mobile;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private @JsonIgnore String password;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="membership_status")
    private MembershipStatus membershipStatus;

    // define constructors
    public User() {
        
    }
    
    public User(List<Authority> authorities, int id, String firstName, String lastName, String gender, LocalDate birthDate,
        String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String town, String county, String country, String postcode,
        String email, String phone, String mobile, String password, MembershipStatus membershipStatus) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    this.town = town;
    this.county = county;
    this.country = country;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.password = password;
    this.membershipStatus = membershipStatus;
}
    
    public List<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }

    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }

    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String getCounty() {
        return county;
    }

    public void setCounty(String county) {
        this.county = county;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
    }

    public MembershipStatus getMembershipStatus() {
        return membershipStatus;
    }

    public void setMembershipStatus(MembershipStatus membershipStatus) {
        this.membershipStatus = membershipStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [authorities=" + authorities + ", id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", gender=" + gender + ", birthDate=" + birthDate + ", addressLine1=" + addressLine1
                + ", addressLine2=" + addressLine2 + ", town=" + town + ", county=" + county + ", country=" + country
                + ", postcode=" + postcode + ", email=" + email + ", phone=" + phone + ", mobile=" + mobile
                + ", password=" + password + ", enabled=" + membershipStatus + "]";
    }
    
}




@Entity
@Table(name="authorities")
public class Authority {    

    @EmbeddedId
    private AuthorityId id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="member_email", referencedColumnName="email", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;
    
    public Authority() {
        
    }

    public Authority(AuthorityId id, User user, String email, String authority) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public AuthorityId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(AuthorityId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        //return email;
        return id.getEmail();
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.id.setEmail(email);
        //this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        //return authority;
        return id.getAuthority();
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.id.setAuthority(authority);
        //this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Authority [user=" + user + ", email=" + id.getEmail() + ", authority=" + id.getAuthority() + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is my UserService

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository = null;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = null;

        try {
            Optional<User> optional = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities =  new ArrayList<>();

            if(optional.isPresent()) {
            authorities = optional.get().getAuthorities().stream()
                                            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getEmail()))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, optional.get().getPassword(), authorities);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException exception) {
            throw exception;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        return user;
    }
```

I don't have a `WebSecurityConfigurer` but I thought the `PasswordEncoder` was taken care of with this:

```
public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
}
```

**Just some more info**

I did some more investigation here and found that the following exception is thrown:

> 2020-12-10 20:07:40.740 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `authorities` : value = NOT NULL COLLECTION
> 2020-12-10 20:07:40.741 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`authorities`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
> 2020-12-10 20:07:40.745  INFO 34468 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.c.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl     : Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.paulcarron.clubmanager.entity.User cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable (com.paulcarron.clubmanager.entity.User is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @409b0635; java.io.Serializable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Am I correct here and if so how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Something wrong with the code you posted.  What does `UserRepository#findByEmail` return? `User`? Or `Optional<User>`?

Comment: The 1st thing I would check is case sensitivity. Maybe your DB uses case sensitive string encoding?  What DB are you using?

Comment: Sorry. I updated `UserRepository`. It's supposed to return `Optional<User>`. I'd tried changing some things and forgot to change that back.

Comment: The DB is MySQL. I don't think case is the issue though.

Comment: The service throws `RuntimeException`, doesn't it?  What is `UsernameNotFoundException`? The stacktrace would be helpul.

Answer (score 0):

`UsernameNotFoundException` is specific to `UserDetailsService`.  If you
haven't configure one explicitly, you might do:

```java
@Configuration
@NoArgsConstructor @ToString @Log4j2
public class UserServicesConfiguration {
    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository = null;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
    private class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
        @Override
        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserDetails details = null;

            try {
                Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);

                details =
                    new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username,
                             user.get().getPassword(),
                             AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList());
            } catch (UsernameNotFoundException exception) {
                throw exception;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
            }

            return details;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `UserDetails` implementation `User` is distinct from your DAO
class.  You'll need to tie the `PasswordEncoder` to the `UserDetailsService`
in a ``WebSecurityConfigurer`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@NoArgsConstructor @Log4j2
public class WebSecurityConfigurerImpl extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private UserDetailsService userDetailsService = null;
    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = null;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests(t -> t.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added some information to my question relating to my UserService.

Comment: Your get/set password methods should not encode the password; they should expect an encoded/encrypted password will be passed/return.  I have also added one more method  to `WebSecurityConfigurerImpl` but the default should work for you.